# Почему получаю не полный ответ Json?

Tags: android, json

Скажите кто знает, в чем проблема может быть? Разбираю json и получаю не полный ответ.
Что то в таком роде:

```
{"estimated_fill":1,"volume":1.1,"address":"Гречка Маршала (Івана Виговського) вул.20, Подільський р-н","lat":50.4918171037732,"lng":30.4071090729485,"id":1013709,"quantity":4},{"estimated_fill":1,"volume":1.1,"address":"Гречка Маршала (Іва�
```

Беру это все с помощью retrofit.

```
@Headers({("X-Signature: reserved"),("Content-Type: text/x-json")})
```

@POST("get_routes/")
Call  getRoutes(@Body Map<String, String> id);

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://...")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
    jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
```

Вот структура:

```
"routes":[
  {
     "platforms":[
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"АТБ-Містечко",
           "lat":50.2107736547029,
           "lng":30.3174322843552,
           "id":1022549,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"пр.Лесі Українки, 15 ",
           "lat":50.1974241245373,
           "lng":30.2944350242615,
           "id":1022542,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Столичка",
           "lat":50.216073975587,
           "lng":30.3178024291992,
           "id":1022543,
           "quantity":3
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Солнечная",
           "lat":50.1883300230983,
           "lng":30.2941560745239,
           "id":1022544,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"вул.Володимирська,13",
           "lat":50.1747131083508,
           "lng":30.3193259239197,
           "id":1022545,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"вул.Володимирька, 28 (Корунд)",
           "lat":50.1733834992561,
           "lng":30.3227108716965,
           "id":1022546,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Фуршет",
           "lat":50.1795055782639,
           "lng":30.3133499622345,
           "id":1022547,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"вул.Набережна",
           "lat":50.1800174337311,
           "lng":30.3084254264832,
           "id":1022548,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Військове .Містечко",
           "lat":50.2120369970609,
           "lng":30.3167670965195,
           "id":1022550,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"вул.Грушевського,25",
           "lat":50.180299123662,
           "lng":30.3108340501785,
           "id":1022551,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Іванковичі",
           "lat":50.2786446089967,
           "lng":30.4251337051392,
           "id":1022552,
           "quantity":2
        }
     ],
     "num":"01.05 - Смаколики",
     "id":1022554,
     "itinerary":""
  }
```

],
"success":true

Пока пытаюсь это все в один List добавить и получаю как бы не полный ответ.

Comment: Сервер точно отдает полный ответ? По-моему, причина в многобайтовых символах. Сервер выдаёт заголовок `Content-length: количество_символов`, а требуется указать количество в байтах. И так как встречаются много-байтовые символы, ответ сервера обрезается.

Comment: И как же это побороть если в этом причина?

Comment: И вот проверил, вывел не через log, а в edit text и увидел полный ответ. А как можно взять на пример объект только с данным ID ("num":"01.05 - Смаколики",
     "id":1022554,
     "itinerary":""). Тогда точно не будет такой проблемы, не будет все списки загружать.

Comment: Значит сам logcat обрезает вывод, а не json у вас обрезанный. Данные с сервера приходят потоком, чтобы добраться до нужного объекта нужно читать поток и разбирать его на лету и при этом нужный объект может оказаться в самом конце. Такой подход не имеет практической пользы, за редкими исключениями. Возможность взять только нужные данные по каким-либо критериям должна быть реализована на стороне сервера через соответствующий запрос с параметрами.

Comment: Получается, мне в любом случае нужно брать объект целым и распускать его чтобы вытащить свое id?